# RLC Circuit using Laplace transform

Tags: passive-networks

[image]

Please help-me in this question, first I calculate the I(s) and I get

$$
I(s) = \dfrac{ \dfrac{1}{s+1} }{ s^2+\frac{R}{L}s+\frac{1}{LC} }
$$

How I proceed to find Vo(t)?

Comment: How doyou express the input voltage and impedence of the components using the Laplace transform? Note that exercises are fine here, but some effort in solving is expected of the poster.

Comment: I(s) = (1/s+1)/((s^2+(R/L)*s+(1/LC))

Comment: You know \$I(s)\$ through capacitor. Calculate \$V_o(s)\$ and get \$V_o(t)\$  by taking its Laplace inverse

Comment: Can u give-me a example, please? Vo(s) = (RSC+1)I(s) ?

Answer (score 1):

First, basic thing:

$$Vo(s) = I(s) \cdot X_C(s)$$

Replace Xc with its Laplace equivalent:

$$X_C = \dfrac{1}{sC}$$

Replace the formulas the first equation and you get the voltage function. You might need to massage the equation to simplify it.

Then you need to anti-transform: you can do it using the rules and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
to resolve this problem I did the following steps,
transform the circuit in S-domain
[image]

then, resolve inverse of \$I(s) \cdot X_C \rightarrow I(s) = \dfrac{1\over s+1}{6+s+10\over s} \$ and Xc = 10/s

\$ \mathcal{L}^-1(I(s) \cdot X_C) \$

and got the correct answer:

\$ V_O (t) = \dfrac{2}{e^t} - \dfrac{2(cos(t) + 2sin(t))}{e^{3t}} \$